# i just try to search the result by the name of school.but the grid view didnt show any thing

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code...i just try to search the result by the name of school.but the grid view didnt show any thing.my code is

```
public void gridfill()
{
    markSp spMark = new markSp();
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    dtbl = spMark.markViewAll();
    gvResult.DataSource = dtbl;
    dtbl = spMark.markViewBySchool(txtSchoolName.Text);
    gvResult.DataSource = dtbl;    
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridfill();
}
public DataTable markViewAll()
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("markViewAll", sqlcon);
    sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
    return dtbl;
}
public DataTable markViewBySchool(string viewBySchool)
{
    DataTable dtbClass = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("markViewBySchool",sqlcon);
    sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@schoolName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = viewBySchool;
    sqlda.Fill(dtbClass);
    return dtbClass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change as below, there are few problems in your code, why two times databinding to same gridview? even you data bind two times it only show what you set at the last time. i have removed few lines of code and you forgot to call `gvResult.DataBind()` as well

```
public void gridfill()
{
    markSp spMark = new markSp();
    gvResult.DataSource = spMark.markViewBySchool(txtSchoolName.Text);
    gvResult.DataBind();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged with ASP.Net, you need to call `DataBind`

```
gvResult.DataBind();
```

So your method would be:

```
public void gridfill()
{
    markSp spMark = new markSp();
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    dtbl = spMark.markViewAll(); //you are not using this anywhere
    gvResult.DataSource = dtbl;  // so you can get rid of these two lines
    dtbl = spMark.markViewBySchool(txtSchoolName.Text);
    gvResult.DataSource = dtbl;    
    gvResult.DataBind(); // This is missing
}
```

You should see: [ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

Comment: @jasel, you are welcome, I guess you are coming from WinForm background, because that should work there. :)

Comment: Note that setting the datatable and setting the datasource twice is a bit... redundant. OP doesn't even need the datatable variable in this case, nor do they need the call to markViewAll().

Comment: @J.Steen, You are right, actually just pointed to the core reason, just added comments for the OP as well in the answer

Comment: @habib, u r right, thnks , i jus confused , actually i knw smthng abt winform, bt nw oly entered into asp, thats y,,,

Comment: @jasel, Remove those two lines commented in the answer, if you are not using them,

Comment: @jasel And *please* write in full words. It's insanely difficult to read, when the rest of the text around it is in proper English. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void gridfill()
{
      markSp spMark = new markSp();
     DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
     dtbl = spMark.markViewAll();

     dtbl = spMark.markViewBySchool(txtSchoolName.Text);
     gvResult.DataSource = dtbl; 
     gvResult.Databind(); // You forgot DataBind()  
  }
```